# Solenoid pull force & Velocity calculation

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity

So I am building a circular accelerator (like a slightly oversimplified model version of CERN) as a physics project, and I'm at a dead end. I believe I need to know how to work out differential equations to answer this, but I'd like to know if there's any other way to get the answer.

Okay. I am calculating the velocity of a projectile after passing through a solenoid. I have a system using an photo-interrupter to switch the coil on when a projectile passes through it.

I know the force of a solenoid can be calculated using $F = (NI)^2\mu_0A/2g^2$ So the first part of my question should be fairly simple I believe. Since the gap between projectile and coil ($g$) changes as the projectile accelerates, the force acting on the projectile become stronger (because the magnetic field diminishes with the square of the distance.)

Can I use the average distance between coil and projectile or must I learn how to work differential equations?

My second question involves the length of time the force from the solenoid is applied. As I have my formulas set up, I know the distance between the photo-interrupter and the coils, I know my starting velocity, and I know the acceleration applied to the projectile (assuming I can use the average force applied).

I made a python program to run through the equation for displacement as a function of time, adding a set amount of time in each run-through, until the displacement was equal to the distance between my interrupter and my coils. I then had it record the number of second it took, rearranged $F=ma$ to get $\frac{F}{m}=a$, used this instead of $a$ in $V = \frac{a}{\Delta t}$ to get $$V=\frac{\frac{F = (NI)^2\mu_0A/2(g_{avg})^2}{\text{Mass of projectile}}}{\Delta t} \,.$$
Is this an accurate way to calculate the velocity?

Comment: Why did you edit in a paragraph at the end to explain how you should have edited the last equations instead of just editing the last equations?

Comment: I've been told that's how its done on the SE system.

Comment: Whoever told you that is mistaken. The point of having an edit function is so that things can be made *better*.

Comment: As long as I am commenting here, I'll mention that I found the beginning very unclear: you start by talking about a particle accelerator (well, you named a lab, but one known for accelerators) and then talk about using a solenoid. Presumably you are planning to accelerate a small piece of metal (like a BB or a bearing), but you never *said* so. My first reaction was *"You can't accelerate a charged particle with a axial magnetic field!"*

Comment: @dmckee Lol, yes. I plan to accelerate a BB. Its for demonstration purposes. To very simply show how CERN works. I could have said electromagnet, if it would have helped. Sorry, I thought saying that it was a model version implied BBs and not protons.

Comment: Anyway, would it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16829/discussion-between-dmckee-and-coilkid).

Comment: Wait, I was right the first time.

Comment: Yes, you were. So go into the edit history (click the time above the editor's icon (currently me)), scroll down to the revision where things were right and hit "revert".